# why is Chrome Developer Tools showing phpMyAdmin with a value in cookies of my site

Tags: cookies, phpmyadmin

suddenly i notice that my website that i created on classic asp shows a cookie phpMyAdmin with a value ?
this happens only after a successful login using a password and username on my site.
the expiry of shows "Session" with path / and size 50
has my site been hacked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had opened my Cpanel PhpMyAdmin and since it was the same domain name, it started showing the phpMyAdmin on this site's cookies as well, As soon as i logged out Cpanel, it stopped showing